# how to assign separate css for websheet in ipad

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a web page i want that web page should load two different css one when it is runing on mobile safari and one for when we save it home screen and then runs on web sheet so how to load different css files for both

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=css+to+target+different+devices

Comment: @RobertHarvey i know this in media queries we define css for ipad landscape or portrait how can we define for  desktop version when we open web page after adding to homescreen it opens without address bar

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=detect+browser+css

Answer (score 1):

You could target the device using [CSS3 Media queries](http://perishablepress.com/target-iphone-and-ipad-with-css3-media-queries/). You'd have to load all CSS and have it detect the device.

Media queries has [a lot of properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries). You just have to use a combination of those queries to target a device. As far as i know, the usual ways to do it is to know the resolutions and orientation.

Comment: yes but when i run on ipad device on safari browser it should load different css can you help me out in this please

Comment: in media queries width of device is same if we launh from mobile safari or the desktop version so how can we make differentiate

Comment: @user1374388 media queries have [lots of properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries) for device detection.

Comment: i have read this but i am unable to find any property related to this if you know can you tell me please